# Union of definable sets is a definable set

Tags: logic, model-theory

I tried to prove this question but without a success: Let $K_1 \text{and } K_2$ be definable sets, prove that $K_1∪K_2$ is definable.

What I tried to do is to assume: $K_1=\text{Ass}(X)=\{v\mid v\models X\}$ and $K_2=\text{Ass}(Y)=\{v\mid v\models Y\}$ and to say that $K1\cup K2=\text{Ass}(X\cap Y)$. But I couldn't prove that: $K_1\cup K_2\supseteq\text{Ass}(X\cap Y)$.

I would like to get help with this proof

Comment: $x\in K_1 \cup K_2 \iff x \in K_1 \lor x \in K_2$.

Comment: So if $\phi_1$ defines $K_1$ and $\phi_2$ defines $K_2$...

Comment: @Carl Mummert: I believe the OP means definability in the context of propositional calculus.

Comment: I am ***more*** than sure that I posted an answer to this question several hours ago.